# If $a,b>0$ and $a+b=2$ , prove that $a^{2b}+b^{2a}+(\frac{a-b}2)^2\leqslant2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a,b>0$ and $a+b=2$ , prove that

$$
a^{2b}+b^{2a}+(\frac{a-b}2)^2\leqslant2
$$

The equality occurs if and only if $(a,b)\sim(1,1)$ or $(a,b)\sim(2,0)$ or its cyclic permutations.

My attempt:

By symmetry and the constraint, we may let $x=a-1=1-b$ , the inequality converts to

$$
(1+x)^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2(1+x)}+x^2\leqslant2
$$

I tried to let $f(x):=(1+x)^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2(1+x)}+x^2$ , but its derrivative is too complicated. I also tried to write $(1+x)^{1-x}$ as $e^{2(1-x)\ln(1+x)}$ and apply inequalities like $\ln x\leqslant x-1$ , $e^x\leqslant\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ and such, but it would be either too complicated or too crude.

How to solve it?

Comment: Not that I expect it to work out nicely, but approaching the problem using Lagrange multipliers may be fruitful.

Comment: Maybe a useless hint...
$$\left( \frac {a-b} {2} \right)^2=1-ab$$

Comment: @O-17 Can i ask for the following refinement : $$f\left(x\right)=(1+x)^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2(1+x)}+x^{2}+x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}+2x^{3}\left(1-x\right)^{3}\leq 2$$ for $x\in(0,1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your approach, WLOG, let $a=1-x, b=1+x$ for some non-negative real $x \in [0, 1)$.  Then we have to show: $f = (1-x)^{2+2x}+(1+x)^{2-2x}+x^2 \leqslant 2$

Using the case of [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) where exponent is in $(0,1)$, we have $(1-x)^{1+x} \leqslant (1-x)(1-x^2)$.
Again by Bernoulli's inequality, $(1+ x)^{1-x} \leqslant 1+ x(1-x) = (1+x-x^2)$

Hence $f \leqslant (1-x)^2(1-x^2)^2+(1+x-x^2)^2+x^2 = 2-x^2(1+x)(1-x)^3\leqslant 2$, with maximum when $x=0 \implies (a,b)=(1,1)$.

--
*Of course, if $x=1$ is possible, then that is a maximum as well, but then one among $a, b \not >0$.*

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but doesn't Bernoulli's inequality work in the other direction?

Comment: @QLimbo Check the link in the post.  If the exponent is $\in (0,1)$, the inequality reverses.  Alternately note for $n>1$, $(1+x)^n\geqslant 1+nx \iff (1+nx)^{1/n}\leqslant 1+x$

Comment: I see, thanks, it's strange that I didn't know this generalized version. In any case, your proof is quite beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Variant @Macavity .

We use a form of the Young's inequality wich is a somewhere a generalization of the Bernoulli's inequality :

Let $a,b>0$ and $0<v<1$ then we have :

$$av+b(1-v)\geq a^vb^{1-v}$$

Taking account of this theorem and putting :

$a=(1+x)$$\quad$$b=1$$\quad$$v=(1-x)$ we get $0< x<1$:

$$(1+x)^{2(1-x)}\leq ((1+x)(1-x)+1-(1-x))^2$$

Again :

$a=(1-x)^2,b=1,v=x$

$$(1-x)^{2x}\leq (1-x)^{2}x+1-x$$

Or :
$$(1-x)^{2x+2}\leq (1-x)^2((1-x)^{2}x+1-x)$$

Adding the inequalities we got :

$$(1-x)^3x^2\geq 0$$

---

---

We have also :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{2^{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}\left(1+x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)}{2}x^{2+\frac{1}{\ln2}-\ln12}+1-x^{2},h(x)=f(1-x),g\left(x\right)=(1+x)^{2(1-x)}$$

Then for $x\in(0,1)$ :

$$h(x)>g(x)$$